# Get unique values by comparing old and new array objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Compare two array of objects to find distinct values by key **number**

Suppose the old object consists of

```
oldChoices = [{"number": 1, "text": "abc" }, {"number": 2, "text": "pqr" }]
```

and new object consists of

```
newChoices = [{"number": 1, "text": "abc" }, {"number": 2, "text": "pqr" }, {"number": 3, "text": "xyz" }]
```

So need to get:

```
[{"number": 3, "text": "xyz" }]
```

Note: 
   *1. Values populate in the newChoices array on the keypress event of the textbox.
    2. newChoices can get value at the start as well.*

**Attempt 1:**

```
var uniqueTemp = [];
$.each(oldChoices, function(x, e1){
   $.each(newChoices, function(y, e2){
      if(e1.number != e2.number){
         uniqueTemp.push(e2);
      }
   });
})
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
var uniqueTemp = [];
oldChoices.filter(function(x){
   if(newChoices.indexOf(x.number) === -1){
    uniqueTemp.push(x);
    return true;
   }else{
    return false;
   }
});
```

**Expected:**

```
[{"number": 3, "text": "xyz" }]
```

Comment: what do you mean with *index* number? is the new array always greater than the original array? what should happen, if not?

Comment: newChoices will always be greater than the oldChoices.

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51109445/two-js-objects-get-a-value-from-first-object-that-it-missing-in-the-second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the new array.

```js
var oldChoices = [{ number: 1, text: "abc" }, { number: 2, text: "pqr" }],
    newChoices = [{ number: 1, text: "abc" }, { number: 2, text: "pqr" }, { number: 3, text: "xyz" }],
    old = new Set(oldChoices.map(({ number }) => number)),
    result = newChoices.filter(({ number }) => !old.has(number));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second attempt is close, just change to:

```
newChoices.filter((x) => {
   return (!oldChoices.find((choice) => choice.number === x.number));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution . Simple use the `flag` for it . 
in `arr` you will have a `unique object` as expected .

```
var oldChoices = [{"number": 1, "text": "abc" }, {"number": 2, "text": "pqr" }]
var newChoices = [{"number": 1, "text": "abc" }, {"number": 2, "text": "pqr" }, {"number": 3, "text": "xyz" }];
var arr = []
var flag = 0;
newChoices.forEach(function(newChoice){
    oldChoices.forEach(function(oldChoice){
        if(oldChoice.number == newChoice.number){
            flag = 1;
        }
    });
    if(flag != 1){
        arr.push(newChoice);
    }
    flag = 0;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic function that calculates the difference of two arrays:

```
let arrayDifference = (v1, v2, cmp = null) => 
  [...v1.filter(o1 => !v2.some(o2 => cmp ? cmp(o1, o2) : o1 === o2)),  
   ...v2.filter(o1 => !v1.some(o2 => cmp ? cmp(o1, o2) : o1 === o2))]
```

Than you can invoke it with the right comparison function:

```
arrayDifference(
  oldChoices,
  newChoices,
  (o1, o2) => o1.number === o2.number
)
```

This function finds the unique objects that occurs both in oldChoices and in newChoices.